# Unstanding JPA propagation of updates across related entities

Tags: jpa, persistence, glassfish-3

UPDATED: I've taken Chris's answer into account but it didn't help - I'm still facing the issue. I've updated the code below to incorporate Chris's answer. Something to note is that when implementing Chris's suggestion, the relations were persisted but not reflected on the view.xhtml page. I had to replace the db object with the  object returned form the call to `GenericDao.update()`.

I've got the following relations:

One Customer to many PurchaseOrders (PO)
One PO to many Invoices.

I've read up on bi-directional relations and I know that if I have a bi-directional relation, I should update both sides of the relation when updating entities.

I perform the following steps:

1. Create a customer (Customer 1)
2. Create a purchase order (Order 1) linked to Customer 1
3. Create an invoice (Invoice 1) linked to Order 1.

What I observe is that all entities and relations are persisted but the list of Customer's Orders is not displayed.

view Customer:
[image: Customers' orders are incorrectly not listed but have been persisted.]

view PurchaseOrder:

[image: Purchase orders' invoices are correctly listed.]

DB queries:

```
> select * from customer;
> +----+------------+
> | ID | NAME       |
> +----+------------+
> |  1 | Customer 1 |
> +----+------------+
> 1 row in set (0.00 sec)
> 
> mysql> select * from purchaseorder;
> +----+---------+-------------+
> | ID | NAME    | customer_id |
> +----+---------+-------------+
> |  1 | Order 1 |           1 |
> +----+---------+-------------+
> 1 row in set (0.00 sec)
> 
> mysql> select * from invoice;
> +----+-----------+------------------+
> | ID | NAME      | purchaseorder_id |
> +----+-----------+------------------+
> |  1 | Invoice 1 |                1 |
> +----+-----------+------------------+
> 1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The DB reflects the relation between the configured entities so I know my changes are being persisted and, as far as I can tell, I've implemented the Customer-PO relation the same ways as the PO-Invoice relation. Since the list of Invoices for PO is updated correctly, I don't think I have a systemic issue so there must be something different between the implementation of Customers-PO and PO-Invoices relations but I can't spot it.

Why don't I see a list of PO's for my Customer even though there are clearly PO's configured for the customer?

Any help will be appreciated.

Classes(truncated for brevity):
Entities
Customer

```
private int id; //@Id and @GeneratedValue(IDENTITY) on getter
private String name;
@OneToMany(mappedBy="customer")
private Set<PurchaseOrder> purchaseOrders;

public Customer()
{
    purchaseOrders = new HashSet<PurchaseOrder> ();
}

public Set<PurchaseOrder> getPurchaseOrders()
{
    return this.purchaseOrders;
}

public void setPurchaseOrders(Set<PurchaseOrder> orders)
{
    this.purchaseOrders = orders;
}

public void addPurchaseOrder(PurchaseOrder purchaseOrder)
{
    this.purchaseOrders.add(purchaseOrder);
    //this IF is important for avoiding an infinite loop
    if (purchaseOrder.getCustomer() != this)
    {
        purchaseOrder.setCustomer(this);
    }
}

public void removePurchaseOrder(PurchaseOrder purchaseOrder)
{
    this.purchaseOrders.remove(purchaseOrder);
    //this IF is important to avoid an infinite loop
    if(purchaseOrder.getCustomer() != null)
    {
        purchaseOrder.removeFromCustomer(this);
    }
}
```

PO

```
private int id; //@Id and identity column
private String name;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="customer_id")
private Customer customer;
@OneToMany(mappedBy="purchaseOrder")
private Set<Invoice> invoices;

public PurchaseOrder() {
    invoices = new HashSet<Invoice> ();
}

public Customer getCustomer()
{
    return this.customer;
}

public void setCustomer(Customer customer)
{
    this.customer = customer;
}

public void addToCustomer(Customer customer)
{
    //this IF is important for avoiding an infinite loop
    if(!customer.getPurchaseOrders().contains(this))
    {
        customer.addPurchaseOrder(this);
    }
    this.customer = customer;
}

public void removeFromCustomer(Customer customer)
{
    //this IF is important for avoiding an infinite loop
    if(customer.getPurchaseOrders().contains(this))
    {
        customer.removePurchaseOrder(this);
    }
    this.customer = null;
}

public Set<Invoice> getInvoices()
{
    return this.invoices;
}

public void setInvoices(Set<Invoice> invoices)
{
    this.invoices = invoices;
}

public void addInvoice(Invoice invoice)
{
    this.invoices.add(invoice);
    //this IF is important for avoiding an infinite loop
    if (invoice.getPurchaseOrder() != this)
    {
        invoice.addToPurchaseOrder(this);
    }
}

public void removeInvoice(Invoice invoice)
{
    this.invoices.remove(invoice);
    //this IF is important to avoid an infinite loop
    if(invoice.getPurchaseOrder() != null)
    {
        invoice.removeFromPurchaseOrder(this);
    }
}
```

Invoice

```
private int id; //@Id and identity column
private String name;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="purchaseorder_id")
private PurchaseOrder purchaseOrder;

public Invoice() {
}

public PurchaseOrder getPurchaseOrder()
{
    return this.purchaseOrder;
}

public void setPurchaseOrder(PurchaseOrder purchaseOrder)
{
    this.purchaseOrder = purchaseOrder;
}

public void addToPurchaseOrder(PurchaseOrder purchaseOrder)
{
    //this IF is important for avoiding an infinite loop
    if(!purchaseOrder.getInvoices().contains(this))
    {
        purchaseOrder.addInvoice(this);
    }
    this.purchaseOrder = purchaseOrder;
}

public void removeFromPurchaseOrder(PurchaseOrder purchaseOrder)
{
    //this IF is important for avoiding an infinite loop
    if(purchaseOrder.getInvoices().contains(this))
    {
        purchaseOrder.removeInvoice(this);
    }
    this.purchaseOrder = null;
}
```

GenericDao (Parent of all other DAOs)

```
@Stateful
public class GenericDao<T extends Serializable, PK> implements IGenericDao<T, PK>
{
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "my_PU")
    protected EntityManager em;

    private Class<T> type;

    public Class<T> getType()
    {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(Class<T> type)
    {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public void create(T newObject)
    {
        em.persist(newObject);
    }

    public T read(PK id)
    {
        return em.find(type, id);
    }

    public T update(T transientObject)
    {
        return em.merge(transientObject);
    }

    public void delete(T objectToDelete)
    {
        em.remove(objectToDelete);
    }

    public T getResultObject(String namedQuery, Map<String, Object> criteria)
    throws DatabaseException
    {
        List<T> records = getResultSetList(namedQuery, criteria);
        if(records.isEmpty())
        {
            return null;
        }
        else if (records.size() != 1)
        {
            throw new DatabaseException("Too many records found!");
        }
        else
        {
            return records.remove(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Controllers
CustomerController

```
@RequestScoped
public class CustomerController extends FormRequestController
{
    @Inject
    private HTMLDataTableActionBean htmlDataTableActionBean;
    @EJB
    private ICustomerDao customerDao;
    @Inject
    private Customer customer;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() throws DatabaseException
    {
        setEntityObjectList(findAll());
        if (null == this.getCustomer())
        {
            setCustomer(new Customer());
        }
    }

    public void processRequest(FormActionToPerform action) throws DatabaseException
    {
        switch (action)
        {
            case SHOW_ADD_VIEW:
                setCustomer(new Customer());
                break;
            case SHOW_VIEW_FOR_LIST:
                setEntityObjectList(findAll());
                break;
            case SHOW_EDIT_VIEW:
            case SHOW_VIEW_TO_VIEW_SELECTED_OBJECT:
                setCustomer((Customer) getHtmlDataTableActionBean()
                        .getSelectedEntityObject());
                break;
            case SHOW_DELETE_VIEW:
                setCustomer((Customer) getHtmlDataTableActionBean()
                        .getSelectedEntityObject());
                delete();
                break;
        }
    }

    public String doShowUIView(FormActionToPerform action)
    {
        String responseURL = "fail.xhtml";
        if (null == this.customer)
        {
            return responseURL;
        }
        else
        {
            switch (action)
            {
                case SHOW_ADD_VIEW:
                    responseURL = "customer.xhtml";
                    break;
                case SHOW_EDIT_VIEW:
                    responseURL = "customer.xhtml";
                    break;
                case SHOW_VIEW_TO_VIEW_SELECTED_OBJECT:
                    responseURL = "viewCustomer.xhtml";
                    break;
                case SHOW_DELETE_VIEW:
                    responseURL = "customerList.xhtml";
                    break;
                case SHOW_VIEW_FOR_LIST:
                    if (this.entityObjectList.size() == 0)
                    {
                        setErrorMessage("No customers to display");
                    }
                    responseURL = "customerList.xhtml";
                    break;
                default:
                    responseURL = "index.xhtml";
            }
        }
        return responseURL;
    }

    public String save()
    {
        String url = "success.xhtml";
        Customer existingCustomer = null;
        try
        {
            existingCustomer =
                    customerDao.getCustomerByName(this.getCustomer().getName());

            if(existingCustomer != null)
            {
                //there's already a customer with this name, don't make a new one
                setErrorMessage("Customer already exists");
                url = "fail.xhtml";
            }

            customerDao.update(customer);
        }
        catch (DatabaseException e)
        {
            setErrorMessage(e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
            url = "fail.xhtml";
        }
        return url;
    }
}
```

POController

```
@RequestScoped
public class PurchaseOrderController extends FormRequestController
{
    @Inject
    private HTMLDataTableActionBean htmlDataTableActionBean;
    @EJB
    private IPurchaseOrderDao purchaseOrderDao;
    @EJB
    private IInvoiceDao invoiceDao;
    @EJB
    private ICustomerDao customerDao;
    @Inject
    private PurchaseOrder purchaseOrder;

    private List<SelectItem> customerList;
    private String selectedCustomer;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() throws DatabaseException
    {
        setEntityObjectList(findAll());
        if (null == purchaseOrder)
        {
            purchaseOrder = new PurchaseOrder();
            setEditMode(false);
        }
    }

    public void processRequest(FormActionToPerform action)
    throws DatabaseException
    {
        switch (action)
        {
            case SHOW_ADD_VIEW:
                setPurchaseOrder(new PurchaseOrder());
                break;
            case SHOW_VIEW_FOR_LIST:
                setEntityObjectList(findAll());
                break;
            case SHOW_EDIT_VIEW:
            case SHOW_VIEW_TO_VIEW_SELECTED_OBJECT:
                {
                    setPurchaseOrder(
                          (PurchaseOrder)getHtmlDataTableActionBean().
                                                     getSelectedEntityObject());
                }
                break;
            case SHOW_DELETE_VIEW:
                {
                    setPurchaseOrder(
                          (PurchaseOrder)getHtmlDataTableActionBean().
                                                     getSelectedEntityObject());
                    delete();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    String doShowUIView(FormActionToPerform action)
    {
        String responseURL = "fail.xhtml";
        switch (action)
        {
            case SHOW_ADD_VIEW:
                responseURL = "purchaseOrder.xhtml";
                break;
            case SHOW_EDIT_VIEW:
                setEditMode(true);
                setComponent(null);
                responseURL = "purchaseOrder.xhtml";
                break;
            case SHOW_DELETE_VIEW:
            case SHOW_VIEW_FOR_LIST:
                if (this.entityObjectList.size() == 0)
                {
                    setErrorMessage("No orders to display");
                }
                responseURL = "purchaseOrderList.xhtml";
                break;

            case SHOW_VIEW_TO_VIEW_SELECTED_OBJECT:
                responseURL = "viewPurchaseOrder.xhtml";
                break;

            default:
                responseURL = HOME;
        }
        return responseURL;
    }

    public String save()
    {
        String responseURL = "fail.xhtml";
        try
        {
            PurchaseOrder dbPurchaseOrder =
               purchaseOrderDao.getPurchaseOrderByName(purchaseOrder.getName());
            if(dbPurchaseOrder == null)
            {
                dbPurchaseOrder = purchaseOrder;
            }

            Customer customer = customerDao.getCustomerByName(selectedCustomer);
            dbPurchaseOrder.addToCustomer(customer);
            purchaseOrder = purchaseOrderDao.update(dbPurchaseOrder);
            //replace the not-yet-persisted dbPurchaseOrder object in customer
            //with the persisted purchaseOrderobject returned from the update()
            //call above.
            customer.removePurchaseOrder(dbPurchaseOrder);
            customer.addPurchaseOrder(purchaseOrder);
            customerDao.update(customer);
            System.out.println("# of Purchase orders for customer: "+
                        purchaseOrder.getCustomer().getPurchaseOrders().size());
            //Output: # of Purchase orders for customer: 1
            responseURL = "success.xhtml";
        }
        catch (DatabaseException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            setErrorMessage(e.toString());
            responseURL = null;
        }
        return responseURL;
    }
}
```

InvoicesController

```
@RequestScoped
public class InvoiceController extends FormRequestController
{
    @Inject
    private HTMLDataTableActionBean htmlDataTableActionBean;
    @EJB
    private IInvoiceDao invoiceDao;
    @Inject
    private Invoice invoice;
    @EJB
    private IPurchaseOrderDao purchaseOrderDao;

    private List<SelectItem> purchaseOrderList;
    private String selectedPurchaseOrder;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() throws DatabaseException
    {
        setEntityObjectList(findAll());
        if (null == invoice)
        {
            invoice = new Invoice();
            setEditMode(false);
        }
    }

    public void processRequest(FormActionToPerform action) throws DatabaseException
    {
        switch (action)
        {
            case SHOW_ADD_VIEW:
                break;
            case SHOW_VIEW_FOR_LIST:
                setEntityObjectList(findAll());
                break;
            case SHOW_EDIT_VIEW:
            case SHOW_VIEW_TO_VIEW_SELECTED_OBJECT:
                {
                    setInvoice((Invoice)getHtmlDataTableActionBean().
                                                     getSelectedEntityObject());
                }
                break;
            case SHOW_DELETE_VIEW:
            {
                setInvoice((Invoice)getHtmlDataTableActionBean().
                                                     getSelectedEntityObject());
                delete();
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    String doShowUIView(FormActionToPerform action)
    {
        String responseUrl = "fail.xhtml";
        if (null == invoice)
        {
            System.out.println("invoice == null");
            return responseUrl;
        }
        else
        {
            switch (action)
            {
                case SHOW_ADD_VIEW:
                    responseUrl = "invoice.xhtml";
                    break;
                case SHOW_EDIT_VIEW:
                    setEditMode(true);
                    setComponent(null);
                    responseUrl = "invoice.xhtml";
                    break;
                case SHOW_VIEW_TO_VIEW_SELECTED_OBJECT:
                    responseUrl = "viewInvoice.xhtml";
                    break;
                case SHOW_DELETE_VIEW:
                case SHOW_VIEW_FOR_LIST:
                    if (this.entityObjectList.size() == 0)
                    {
                        setErrorMessage("no invoices to display");
                    }
                    responseUrl = "invoiceList.xhtml";
                    break;
                default:
                    responseUrl = "index.xhtml";
            }
        }
        return responseUrl;
    }

    public String save()
    {
        String responseUrl = "fail.xhtml";
        try
        {
            Invoice dbInvoice = invoiceDao.getInvoiceByName(invoice.getName());
            if(dbInvoice == null)
            {
                //this is a new invoice
                dbInvoice = invoice;
            }
            PurchaseOrder purchaseOrder =
                 purchaseOrderDao.getPurchaseOrderByName(selectedPurchaseOrder);
            dbInvoice.addToPurchaseOrder(purchaseOrder);
            invoice = invoiceDao.update(dbInvoice);
            //replace the not-yet-persisted dbInvoice object in purchaseOrder
            //with the persisted invoice object returned from the update() call above.
            purchaseOrder.removeInvoice(dbInvoice);
            purchaseOrder.addInvoice(invoice);
            purchaseOrderDao.update(purchaseOrder);
            System.out.println("# of Invoices for purchase order: "+
                               invoice.getPurchaseOrder().getInvoices().size());
            //Output: # of Invoices for purchase order: 1
            responseUrl = "success.xhtml";
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
            setErrorMessage(e.toString());
        }
        return responseUrl;
    }
}
```

FormRequestController

```
public abstract class FormRequestController implements NavigationConstants
{

    protected enum FormActionToPerform {
        SHOW_ADD_VIEW,
        SHOW_EDIT_VIEW,
        SHOW_DELETE_VIEW,
        SHOW_VIEW_TO_VIEW_SELECTED_OBJECT,
        SHOW_VIEW_FOR_LIST;
    }

    protected FacesContext context;
    protected List<?> entityObjectList;
    private UIComponent component;
    protected boolean editMode;
    protected String componentId = null;

    public String showViewDataTable() throws DatabaseException {
        processRequest(FormActionToPerform.SHOW_VIEW_FOR_LIST);
        return doShowUIView(FormActionToPerform.SHOW_VIEW_FOR_LIST);
    }

    public String showViewToAdd() throws DatabaseException {
        processRequest(FormActionToPerform.SHOW_ADD_VIEW);
        return doShowUIView(FormActionToPerform.SHOW_ADD_VIEW);
    }

    public String showViewToEdit() throws DatabaseException {
        processRequest(FormActionToPerform.SHOW_EDIT_VIEW);
        return doShowUIView(FormActionToPerform.SHOW_EDIT_VIEW);
    }

    public String showViewToDeleteDetails() throws DatabaseException {
        processRequest(FormActionToPerform.SHOW_DELETE_VIEW);
        return doShowUIView(FormActionToPerform.SHOW_DELETE_VIEW);
    }

    public String showViewToViewDetails() throws DatabaseException {
        processRequest(FormActionToPerform.SHOW_VIEW_TO_VIEW_SELECTED_OBJECT);
        return doShowUIView(FormActionToPerform.SHOW_VIEW_TO_VIEW_SELECTED_OBJECT);
    }

    abstract String doShowUIView(FormActionToPerform action);
    abstract void processRequest(FormActionToPerform action) throws DatabaseException;

    protected void bindData() {

    }

    abstract String save();
    abstract void delete() throws DatabaseException;

    public List<?> getEntityObjectList() {
        return entityObjectList;
    }

    public void setEntityObjectList(List<?> entityObjectList) {
        this.entityObjectList = entityObjectList;
    }

    public FacesContext getContext() {
        setContext(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
        return context;
    }

    public void setContext(FacesContext context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public UIComponent getComponent() {
        return component;
    }

    public void setComponent(UIComponent component) {
        this.component = component;
    }
}
```

I'm iterating over the `Customer#purchaseOrders` and `PurchaseOrder#invoices` using a `h:dataTable`. SO keeps misidentifying my JSF code as misformatted code and telling me to indent it as such so I can't show my webpage code but hopefully there's enough above to spot my mistake.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You should not have logic within the set/get methods if JPA is set to use property access.  The logic within the set methods will cause JPA to trigger lazy collections etc when building entities and might have other adverse affects depending on the provider internals.  I would either switch your annotations so they are on the fields, or remove the

```
if(!purchaseOrder.getInvoices().contains(this))
{
    purchaseOrder.addInvoice(this);
}
```

logic from the set methods.  The application can still use the addInvoice and have it set both sides of the relationship as the addInvoice methods are not used by JPA when loading entities.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I wasn't aware there was a difference between setting the annotation on the field and on the get/set methods - none of the tutorials I'd read covered that (at least not that I remember). Now I know what I did wrong but I still don't know why it worked for the PO-Invoice relation but not the Customer-PO relation.

Comment: If moving the annotations resolves the issue, then it is due to the timing on how and when the JPA provider builds your entities and calls each method.  Accessing the collection before the provider built it might cause it to think its done building the collection, keeping it empty.  It depends on the provider's internals, but logic in the accessor methods used by JPA will cause trouble more often then not.

Comment: Well now I'm not seeing the Invoices in the PO either so it's a step back. BUT, at least the behaviour is now consistent across entities which is better. The biggest issue was the inconsistency which was confusing me but you've helped identify that.